# What is ZuckMail ?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-headers

```
X-Mailer: ZuckMail [version 1.00]
```

I mean is this custom-made smtp mailer? or X-Mailer header with custom value like X-Mailer:myMailer ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the `X-Mailer` header to anything you want so it was probably the script developers pet name. In this case I would guess it is an email from [Facebook with Zuck](http://blog.kylemulka.com/2006/03/zuckmail/) being short for [Mark Zuckerberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Zuckerberg).

Comment: Ok but what is this http://zuckmail.net

Comment: It is a holding webpage. As for what will eventually appear there you will need to wait for summer 2012 as the site itself says. I am not sure what you are expecting here I can only see as much as you can.

Comment: :D :D yeah but maybe it is custom-made smtp mailer not just changed value and that is interesting

Comment: http://ZuckMail.net is now defunct so I guess it was nothing. HTH.